# xamarin WebResponse not received when Release Mode

Tags: android, xamarin

xamarin - android mode

i can received WebResponse well as i expected in Debug Mode.
but in Release Mode, i can't received WebResponse stream.

is any wrong?
this is my code.

```
public static string WebClientGet(string URI)
{    
    if (Common.IsNetwork() == false) { 
        return null;
    } 
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URI);
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
    request.Accept = "application/json";
    request.Timeout = 10000;
    int euckrCodepage = 51949;
    try
    {
        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        {

            using (Stream s = (response).GetResponseStream ()) { 
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(s, Encoding.GetEncoding(euckrCodepage)))
                {
                    string sss = sr.ReadToEnd(); 
                    return sss;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {

    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: I'm a long way from a bug reproduction project for filing to Xamarin, but I ran into the same issue on a large project (Xamarin Studio v5.7, Xamarin.Android v4.20.0.28). Debug works, release fails, but only on one specific request (but always, even when re-issued). All other requests appeared to work fine. When I hooked the device into a sniffing proxy, the "failing" request goes out and the response comes back as expected in the proxy, but .NET never gets it back in `request.GetResponse()`.

Comment: Scratch that. I was able to nail my issue down to a bug in Json.NET 6.0.6 running on Android. So...not related, after all.